# Nfs server thread count is increased, but new threads don't start

Tags: nfs, rhel6, threads

We're running an nfs-server on RedHat 6.9 Santiago and recently we've experienced large I/O waits on clients. After some troubleshooting we decided to increase the number of nfs threads.

After following the steps in [RHEL's official solutions site(publicly available)](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2216) we edited `/etc/sysconfig/nfs` file and changed the line `RPCNFSDCOUNT=8` to `RPCNFSDCOUNT=16`.

Questions is, reading `/proc/fs/nfsd/thread` and `/proc/net/rps/nfsd` files shows there are still 8 threads. Also grepping `nfsd` processes in `ps` output result in 8 processes.

Finally seeing [this document](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/storage_administration_guide/s1-nfs-start) asserting a reload operation, we did

> service nfs reload

but nothing changed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should restart the service in order to activate the threads;

```
systemctl restart nfs
```

for reference; the settings have changed to : /etc/nfs.conf